# How to find a hidden string in multiple directories

Tags: linux, grep, string

I have bunch of directories with each and every one of them containing a file.
Now some of these files are hidden.
I need to find a string that's in one of the hidden files.

I tried

```
fgrep -r "*medium*" .

find . | fgrep '*medium*'
```

medium is the string that I need to find. None of these commands find the word that I need.

Comment: Is the string you are searching for `medium` or `*medium*`?

Comment: Please clarify your question if it hasn't been answered.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -r --include=.* medium .
```

man grep:

```
   --include=GLOB
          Search  only  files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard
          matching as described under --exclude).
```

Comment: Aren't hidden files searched anyway?

Comment: Yes, but the question was to search in hidden files _only_.

Comment: This one doesn't find it either. I think my question is not clear. There are bunch of text files in every single sub directory and all of them has the string "Hello world" that one i can find easy. what i need to find is the one with the string "medium".

Comment: If you're using the wildcard to match a regexp, use grep -rE (you must understand what the wldcard means in this case). if you're searching for the exact string, use grep -r "medium" or fgrep -r "medium".

Comment: I think the question isn't clear.  This answers it as stated, but I suspect @SajaPeiris means the file is *hard to find* rather than actually "hidden."  (Just a suspicion based on the wording of the question and the comment above.)  Or, the file is hidden using e.g. macOS Finder settings rather than a dot-name.  Anyway, upvoted for the --include flag.